# Are integral functions of continuous functions of bounded variation?

Tags: derivatives, bounded-variation

Given a continuous function $f$, can we say that the integral function 
$F(t)=\int_{t_0}^t f(s) ds$ is of bounded variation?

Comment: Such functions are absolutely continuous by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (Lebesgue version). So $f$ is BV (of any compact interval)

Comment: @AdamMartens: Could you elaborate ? I don't see in what fundamental theorem of calculus (Lebesgue version) gives that $f$ is BV. Thanks you.

Comment: There seems to be some difference of opinion here. That's probably because it does follow that $f$ is _locally_ BV, but not globally. Inn fact $f$ is BV on all of $\Bbb R$ if and only if $\int|f|<\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

- **If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$:** Then $f$ is bounded, i.e., there is $M>0$ s.t. $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Therefore $$|F(t)-F(s)|=\leq \int_s^t |f(x)|\,\mathrm d x\leq M|s-t|,$$
  for all $s,t\in [a,b]$. Therefore, it has bounded variation on $[a,b]$.
- **If $f$ is locally $L^1(a,b)$ only :**

Set$$f^{+}(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}\quad \text{and}\quad f^-(x)=-\min\{f(x),0\},$$ then $f^+$ and $f^-$ are positive. Therefore $$t\mapsto \int_0^tf^+(x)\,\mathrm d x\quad \text{and}\quad t\mapsto \int_0^tf^-(x)\,\mathrm d x$$
are increasing. Since $$F(t)=\int_0^t f^+(x)\,\mathrm d x-\int_0^t f^-(x)\,\mathrm d x,$$
(becaue $f(x)=f^+(x)-f^-(x)$), you can write $F$ as a difference of two increasing function. And thus, it has bounded variation.

Comment: Thank you, quite easy after all..

Comment: @JanisPapewalis: I didn't pay attention to the fact that $f$ is continuous. So it's even easier. I edited my answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: On compact... I edited.

Comment: In the first part it might be better too conclude "$f$ has V on $[a,b]$' instead of "$f$ has BV". If $f'$ is locally integrable I reallly think saying that $f$ has BV is wrong. It's not true the the difference of two monotone fuunctions muust be BV. For example $f(t)=t$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Thank you :-)